# JScrollPane in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I wrote a little code to see how the scroll Pane functions but my code never worked.
here's the code,

```
public Fenetre(){
this.setTitle("Data Simulator");
this.setSize(300, 300);
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
String hello = "hello";
int number = 69;
JPanel content = new JPanel();
content.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
//Box imad = Box.createHorizontalBox();
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
JLabel imad = new JLabel();
imad.setText(hello + " your favorite number is " + number + "\nRight?");
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 110));

scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setEnabled(true);
scrollPane.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);
scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
scrollPane.setViewportView(imad);
add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//---------------------------------------------
//On ajoute le conteneur
scrollPane.add(textArea);
scrollPane.add(imad);
content.add(textArea);
content.add(imad);
content.add(scrollPane);
this.setContentPane(content);
this.setVisible(true);
this.setResizable(false);
```

}
When I run it, I get a little window with the textArea and next to the text area a very little white square, which is the scrollpane i suppose because when I remove it from the code, this square disappears. When I write in the text area and exceed the window's dimension, I can't scroll vertically using the mouse wheel, and not horizontally at all. I saw many examples on internet and I can't understand why my code doesn't work??
Any help explaining how scrollpane works?

Answer (score 3):

```
scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
scrollPane.setViewportView(imad);
```

Only one component can be added to the viewport of the scroll pane, so the label replaces the text area.

```
content.add(textArea);
content.add(imad);
```

A component can only have a single parent. The above code removes the label from the scrollpane, so nothing is now in the scrollpane.

Try something like:

```
JScrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
JPanel content = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
content.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
content.add(imad, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
setContentPane( content );
```

For a better solution, start with the working example found in the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) and then modify the code. This way you will start with a better structured program that follows Swing standards.