# Adding a JScrollPane to my window

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I am trying to make a variable size interface. However, currently, if the size of all components is greater than the dimension of the window, then those begin to
distort ! Therefore, I would like to add a JScrollPane to be displayed when the window size is no longer sufficient, in order to avoid this distortion.
I just started by adding a JScrollPane (as shown on the code bellow), but it does not seem to work, and I am not sure what to change now.

```
JScrollPane myScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
myWindow.getContentPane().add(myScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Here is a simple example of what I have tried:

```
static void one(String[] ari, JLabel sess_nb, Box boxy, long[] res){
    int p;
    int length = ari.length;
    Border cadre = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
    Font police = new Font("Monospaced 13", Font.BOLD, 18);
    Font police1 = new Font("Monospaced 13", Font.BOLD, 15);
    Font font = new Font("Monospaced 13", Font.ITALIC, 13);
    for (p=0;p<length;p++){
        Box boxz = Box.createVerticalBox();
        JLabel Rate = new JLabel("Rating Group "+r);
        JLabel rg_reser = new JLabel();
        JLabel switsh = new JLabel("1");
        JLabel reser = new JLabel(); //in this label the resrvation for each update and each rating group will be stocked
        JLabel consump = new JLabel(); //in this label will be stocked the consumption
        //----------------------------------------------------

        //choice of MB or kB
        JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
        combo.addItem("Megabytes");
        combo.addItem("Bytes");
        combo.addItem("kilobytes");
        combo.addItem("Gigabytes");
        JLabel upload = new JLabel("Upload consumption:");
        JTextField upload_entry = new JTextField("7.5");
        JLabel download = new JLabel("Download consumption:");
        JTextField download_entry = new JTextField("7.5");
        JTextField total_entry = new JTextField();
        JLabel total = new JLabel("Total consumption:");
        JButton rg = new JButton("Next");
        JLabel update = new JLabel("Result here");
        boxz.add(Rate);
        boxz.add(total);
        boxz.add(total_entry);
        boxz.add(upload);
        boxz.add(upload_entry);
        boxz.add(download);
        boxz.add(download_entry);
        boxz.add(combo);
        boxz.add(rg);
        boxz.add(update);
        boxy.add(boxz);
        scrollPane1.add(boxy);        
    }
```

**EDIT** Here is a new test code that I have tried, but it also does not work:

```
public Fenetre(){
    this.setTitle("Data Simulator");
    this.setSize(300, 300);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    String hello = "hello";
    int number = 69;
    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    //Box imad = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
    JLabel imad = new JLabel();
    imad.setText(hello + " your favorite number is " + number + "\nRight?");
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 110));

    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setEnabled(true);
    scrollPane.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(imad);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //---------------------------------------------
    //On ajoute le conteneur
    content.add(imad);
    content.add(textArea);
    content.add(scrollPane);
    this.setContentPane(content);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
}
```

A small white scare appears (I think it is the scroll bar or scroll panel?) and the components in the window exceeds the windows size but nothing happens when I try to scroll (using the mouse or by clinking on the white scare). I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Quit multi posting the same question and quit posting the same question under two user ids: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218224/jscrollpane-in-java

Answer (score 1):

A scrollpane can contain only one component.  Each time you call `setViewportView()` you replace the previously set component.  Also, components can have only one parent.  When you later call `content.add(textArea);` you remove the component from the scrollpane and put it in the panel.

So, remove the incorrect code, make `content` be the scrollpane's viewport and add the scrollpane to the frame:

```
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setEnabled(true);
scrollPane.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);
scrollPane.setViewportView(content);
add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
this.setVisible(true);
this.setResizable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

As dsh says, JScrollPane can have only a single view. As a note on Swing use, I always prefer to create panels inside out: create the child components then lay them out into the new container (init then layout). Otherwise you can lose track of where components are added too easily.

I've updated your example to (probably) work

```
public Fenetre(){
    super("Data Simulator");
    setSize(300, 300);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 110));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    String hello = "hello";
    int number = 69;

    // Create and initialise the child components - smallest details first
    //Box imad = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
    JLabel imad = new JLabel();
    imad.setText(hello + " your favorite number is " + number + "\nRight?");

    // Layout the content panel
    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    content.add(imad);
    content.add(textArea);
    content.add(scrollPane);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(content, HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setEnabled(true);
    scrollPane.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);

    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //---------------------------------------------
    // probably call "pack()" to fit the window to the content based on their preferred sizes
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
}
```

I've taken the liberty to use the JScrollPane(Component, int, int) constructor and a couple of other changes.